Use the node-voltage method to find vo in the circuit shown. 4.4 James_W._Nilsson_Susan_Riedel_Electric_Circuits 5th
Question Statement
I'm not sure where did I do wrong, I was able to compute the right answer with MCM
[writing]
code

I'm not sure where did you do wrong either; I don't see your attempt here.

Also, what's the diamond shaped object, that seems to be labelled with 20-times the current of the voltage source in the lower-right of the diagram.

Also also, the source code is short enough to copy-paste into the Question box.  Why are you hiding easily copied text in a picture on some other site?  Do you intend that no future person could benefit from the work here by finding it in the Search facility?  (When you edit your Question to insert to the source, put four spaces at the beginning of each code line so that it will be rendered as preformatted text.)

Also also also, you use v1, v2, and v3 in your code.  To what in the diagram do these variables correspond?

Your source citation goes better in the body of the text that in the title.  The title is a short summary, not a place to put references or footnotes.
